# Proporção de página em html5

Tags: html, html5, phpmailer

Tenho um código em html que estou usando para envio de email através do phpmailer.
O problema é que o background da página está mto grande e gostaria de saber se tem como eu diminuir esse tamanho.
Segue o código da página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>Bootstrap CRUD Data Table for Database with Modal Form</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body {
   color: #566787;
   background: #70879a;
   font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
   }
   
   .table-wrapper {
   background: #fff;
   padding: 20px 25px;
   margin: 30px 25%;
   border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
   }
   
   .table-title {
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   background: #435d7d;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 16px 30px;
   margin: -20px -5% 10px;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   }
   .table-title h2 {
   margin: 5px 0 0;
   font-size: 24px;
   }
   .table-title .btn-group {
   float: right;
   }
   .table-title .btn {
   color: #fff;
   float: right;
   font-size: 13px;
   border: none;
   min-width: 50px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: none;
   outline: none !important;
   margin-left: 10px;
   }
   .table-title .btn i {
   float: left;
   font-size: 21px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   }
   .table-title .btn span {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 2px;
   }
   table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
   border-color: #e9e9e9;
   padding: 12px 15px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   table.table tr th:first-child {
   width: 60px;
   }
   table.table tr th:last-child {
   width: 100px;
   }
   
   {
   background-color:transparent !important;
   }
   
   table.table-striped.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   }
   table.table th i {
   font-size: 13px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   } 
   table.table td:last-child i {
   opacity: 0.9;
   font-size: 22px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   }
   table.table td a {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #566787;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   outline: none !important;
   }
   table.table td a:hover {
   color: #2196F3;
   }
   table.table td a.edit {
   color: #FFC107;
   }
   table.table td a.delete {
   color: #F44336;
   }
   table.table td i {
   font-size: 19px;
   }
   table.table .avatar {
   border-radius: 50%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: 10px;
   }
   .pagination {
   float: right;
   margin: 0 0 5px;
   }
   .pagination li a {
   border: none;
   font-size: 13px;
   min-width: 30px;
   min-height: 30px;
   color: #999;
   margin: 0 2px;
   line-height: 30px;
   border-radius: 2px !important;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0 6px;
   }
   .pagination li a:hover {
   color: #666;
   } 
   .pagination li.active a, .pagination li.active a.page-link {
   background: #03A9F4;
   }
   .pagination li.active a:hover {        
   background: #0397d6;
   }
   .pagination li.disabled i {
   color: #ccc;
   }
   .pagination li i {
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-top: 6px
   }
   .hint-text {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-size: 13px;
   }    
   /* Custom checkbox */
   .custom-checkbox {
   position: relative;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox'] {    
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
   z-index: 9;
   }
   .custom-checkbox label:before{
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   }
   .custom-checkbox label:before {
   content: '';
   margin-right: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: text-top;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 2;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 6px;
   top: 3px;
   width: 6px;
   height: 11px;
   border: solid #000;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
   transform: inherit;
   z-index: 3;
   transform: rotateZ(45deg);
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
   border-color: #03A9F4;
   background: #03A9F4;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
   border-color: #fff;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:disabled + label:before {
   color: #b8b8b8;
   cursor: auto;
   box-shadow: none;
   background: #ddd;
   }
   /* Modal styles */
   .modal .modal-dialog {
   max-width: 400px;
   }
   .modal .modal-header, .modal .modal-body, .modal .modal-footer {
   padding: 20px 30px;
   }
   .modal .modal-content {
   border-radius: 3px;
   }
   .modal .modal-footer {
   background: #ecf0f1;
   border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
   }
   .modal .modal-title {
   display: inline-block;
   }
   .modal .form-control {
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-color: #dddddd;
   }
   .modal textarea.form-control {
   resize: vertical;
   }
   .modal .btn {
   border-radius: 2px;
   min-width: 100px;
   } 
   .modal form label {
   font-weight: normal;
   } 
   
   .container-non-responsive {
   /* Margin/padding copied from Bootstrap */
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   align: center;
   
   /* Set width to your desired site width */
   width: 1170px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='container-non-responsive'>
   <div class='table-wrapper'>
    <div class='table-title'>
     <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
       <h2>Portabilidade <b>Cadastro Alterado</b></h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <table class='table table-hover'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Situação inicial:</th>
                        <td>$situacao</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Contrato:</th>
                        <td>$contrato</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
                        <th>Cliente:</th>
                        <td>$cliente</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CPF/CNPJ:</th>
                        <td>$cpf</td>
     </tr>     
     <tr>
                        <th>NÚMERO:</th>
                        <td>$numero</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
                        <th>Operadora:</th>
                        <td>$operadora</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
                        <th>Solicitante:</th>
                        <td>$solicitante</td>
     </tr>
     <th>Data da Solicitação:</th>
     <td>$dt_sol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>Via: </th>
     <td><a href='http://portabilidade.tvn-slz.com.br' style='color: green'>Portabilidades</a></td> 
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Gostaria do tamanho delimitado pela linha vermelha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi, Você quer aumentar o tamanho do form é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo.

Comment: Qual a margem da linha vermelha?

Comment: Na realidade não tenho um espaço específico. Gostaria só que ficasse mais ou menos compatível com a imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma possibilidade é alterar as margens na classe *.table-wrapper* e corrigir as margens da classe *.table-title* de acordo com o padding

```
.table-wrapper {
  margin: 30px 15%;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}
.table-title {
    margin: -20px -25px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>Bootstrap CRUD Data Table for Database with Modal Form</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body {
   color: #566787;
   background: #70879a;
   font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
   }
   
   .table-wrapper {
   background: #fff;
   padding: 20px 25px;
   margin: 30px 15%;
   border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
   }
   
   .table-title {
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   background: #435d7d;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 16px 30px;
   margin: -20px -25px 0px;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   }
   .table-title h2 {
   margin: 5px 0 0;
   font-size: 24px;
   }
   .table-title .btn-group {
   float: right;
   }
   .table-title .btn {
   color: #fff;
   float: right;
   font-size: 13px;
   border: none;
   min-width: 50px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: none;
   outline: none !important;
   margin-left: 10px;
   }
   .table-title .btn i {
   float: left;
   font-size: 21px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   }
   .table-title .btn span {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 2px;
   }
   table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
   border-color: #e9e9e9;
   padding: 12px 15px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   table.table tr th:first-child {
   width: 60px;
   }
   table.table tr th:last-child {
   width: 100px;
   }
   
   {
   background-color:transparent !important;
   }
   
   table.table-striped.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   }
   table.table th i {
   font-size: 13px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   } 
   table.table td:last-child i {
   opacity: 0.9;
   font-size: 22px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   }
   table.table td a {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #566787;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   outline: none !important;
   }
   table.table td a:hover {
   color: #2196F3;
   }
   table.table td a.edit {
   color: #FFC107;
   }
   table.table td a.delete {
   color: #F44336;
   }
   table.table td i {
   font-size: 19px;
   }
   table.table .avatar {
   border-radius: 50%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: 10px;
   }
   .pagination {
   float: right;
   margin: 0 0 5px;
   }
   .pagination li a {
   border: none;
   font-size: 13px;
   min-width: 30px;
   min-height: 30px;
   color: #999;
   margin: 0 2px;
   line-height: 30px;
   border-radius: 2px !important;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0 6px;
   }
   .pagination li a:hover {
   color: #666;
   } 
   .pagination li.active a, .pagination li.active a.page-link {
   background: #03A9F4;
   }
   .pagination li.active a:hover {        
   background: #0397d6;
   }
   .pagination li.disabled i {
   color: #ccc;
   }
   .pagination li i {
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-top: 6px
   }
   .hint-text {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-size: 13px;
   }    
   /* Custom checkbox */
   .custom-checkbox {
   position: relative;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox'] {    
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
   z-index: 9;
   }
   .custom-checkbox label:before{
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   }
   .custom-checkbox label:before {
   content: '';
   margin-right: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: text-top;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 2;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 6px;
   top: 3px;
   width: 6px;
   height: 11px;
   border: solid #000;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
   transform: inherit;
   z-index: 3;
   transform: rotateZ(45deg);
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
   border-color: #03A9F4;
   background: #03A9F4;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
   border-color: #fff;
   }
   .custom-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:disabled + label:before {
   color: #b8b8b8;
   cursor: auto;
   box-shadow: none;
   background: #ddd;
   }
   /* Modal styles */
   .modal .modal-dialog {
   max-width: 400px;
   }
   .modal .modal-header, .modal .modal-body, .modal .modal-footer {
   padding: 20px 30px;
   }
   .modal .modal-content {
   border-radius: 3px;
   }
   .modal .modal-footer {
   background: #ecf0f1;
   border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
   }
   .modal .modal-title {
   display: inline-block;
   }
   .modal .form-control {
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-color: #dddddd;
   }
   .modal textarea.form-control {
   resize: vertical;
   }
   .modal .btn {
   border-radius: 2px;
   min-width: 100px;
   } 
   .modal form label {
   font-weight: normal;
   } 
   
   .container-non-responsive {
   /* Margin/padding copied from Bootstrap */
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   align: center;
   
   /* Set width to your desired site width */
   width: 1170px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='container-non-responsive'>
   <div class='table-wrapper'>
    <div class='table-title'>
     <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
       <h2>Portabilidade <b>Cadastro Alterado</b></h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <table class='table table-hover'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Situação inicial:</th>
                        <td>$situacao</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Contrato:</th>
                        <td>$contrato</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
                        <th>Cliente:</th>
                        <td>$cliente</td>
     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CPF/CNPJ:</th>
                        <td>$cpf</td>
     </tr>     
     <tr>
                        <th>NÚMERO:</th>
                        <td>$numero</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
                        <th>Operadora:</th>
                        <td>$operadora</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
                        <th>Solicitante:</th>
                        <td>$solicitante</td>
     </tr>
     <th>Data da Solicitação:</th>
     <td>$dt_sol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>Via: </th>
     <td><a href='http://portabilidade.tvn-slz.com.br' style='color: green'>Portabilidades</a></td> 
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

Existe tbm um controle da largura na div *.container-non-responsive*
No caso pode modificar aqui tbm:

```
.container-non-responsive{
    width: 1170px;
}
```

Comment: Tem como só dar um zoom?

Comment: Vc quer maior? é só mudar a margem lateral

Comment: tipo muda para margin: 30px 0px;

Comment: Ou melhor ... Tem como delimitar de acordo com a linha vermelhar para que o back grou fique só daquele tamanho tamanho? Ou seja, deixar o background do tamanho do tamanho da linha vermelha

Comment: altere os valores nessas classes e vc obterá sua resposta. Vc precisa só ajustar os pixels.